# Changing cold air return vent hole shape

Tags: hvac, ventilation

My house was built in 1980 and the vents are bulky and outdated. The cold air return vents are right angle triangle shaped coming very far out from the wall. Upon removing the vent cover, the hole is part wall and part floor. If I were to make the wall portion of hole taller, could I cover the floor portion up so I can use a flat vent cover?

Comment: Please post some photos, it will make it clearer what your problem is